# Geometry with triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Any other solutions(advice) are welcome.

$\angle BAC=60^\circ, \;\;\;\angle ACB=x,\;\;\; \overline {BD}=\overline{BC}=\overline{CE}  $

[image]

Comment: If you want to see a solution that is different from the image you provided, it is better to describe what direction or type of approach you'd like to see. Basically if you don't show **your own thoughts and efforts**, the post will most likely be ignored or closed by community votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

$$\angle CBA=120^\circ-x$$

Triangle $DBC$ is isosceles:

$$\angle CDB=\angle DCB=\frac12\angle CBA=60^\circ-\frac x2$$

Triangle $BCE$ is isosceles:

$$\angle CEB=\angle CBE=\frac12\angle BCA=\frac x2$$

Now, from triangle:

$$\angle BFC=120^\circ$$

Take a look at quadrilateral $ABFC$: The sum of opposite angles $\angle A$ and $\angle F$ is $180^\circ$ so quadrialteral $ABCD$ is cyclic. Because of that:

$$\angle FAB=\angle FCB=60^\circ-\frac x2=\angle FDB$$

So triangle $FAD$ is isosceles and:

$$FA=FD\tag{1}$$

In a similar way:

$$\angle FAC=\angle FBC=\frac x2=\angle FEA$$

So triangle $FEA$ is isosceles and:

$$FA=FE\tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2) you have:

$$FD=FE$$

...and triangle $FDE$ must be isosceles. Angle $\angle DFE=120^\circ$ and therefore:

$$\angle FDE=\angle FED=30^\circ$$

It follows that:

$$\angle DEA=\angle DEF+\angle FEA=30^\circ+\frac x2$$

Comment: In the very last line you mean $\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: @rogerl Thanks, I have corrected that.

Comment: @Oldboy Wow. very nice. I learned a lot from your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing the rhombus is a nice way to start but we can finish differently.

As soon as you find that $\triangle BDF$ is equilateral, you know that
$FD = FB = FE.$ That is, the points $D,$ $B,$ and $E$ all lie on the same circle with center at $F.$

Referring to this same circle, since the central angle $\angle BFD$ is $60^\circ,$
the inscribed angle $\angle BED$ is $30^\circ.$

We have $\angle CEF = \angle ACB = x$ and $EB$ is the angle bisector of
$\angle CEF,$ so $\angle CEB = \frac12 \angle CEF = \frac 12x.$

Then $\angle CED = \angle CEB + \angle BED = \frac 12x + 30^\circ.$

Comment: Yes, good idea. This is a clean finish.